# Splitting worldwide roads into multiple road datasets with less than threshold number of features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, error-999999, error-999998

I want to split a worldwide 'road dataset' into multiple grids/blocks-extents, depending on the amount of features resides in that block-extent. If the amount of features(inside that block) is still above the count of features I want, then it must split the first block into too pieces and so on..., until it has the right amount of features inside that block-extent before I can use an function like PolygonToRaster and after that the mosaic function.

I came up with this route/possible solution, because i have a lot of errors while trying to raster-rise worldwide road datasets.

> ExecuteErrors:ERROR 999998 and 999999: Unexpected Error.
>
> Failed to execute(PolygonToRaster).

So, if anyone have some experience with this issue, I would gladly know how to solve this issue!

Comment: If this is just a one-off operation (you only need to convert the roads once) then it may be faster to simply create a regular mesh polygon with a small square size, use it to cut up your roads, and rasterize those (rather than spending lots of time coming up with the ultimate, most efficient algorithm which you'll never use again)

Comment: It seems to be an interesting problem. By curiosity, could you explain why you want to do that? Maybe vector tiling, spatial indexing and generalisation could be relevant techniques for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem may not be the number of features, but rather the complexity of some of those features, so you may want to look at the **[Dice](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000037000000)** tool which:

> Subdivides a feature into smaller features based on a specified vertex
>   limit.

This may or may not resolve your ExecuteErrors.

Also, it requires you to have an Advanced level license of ArcGIS for Desktop so may or may not be suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your purpose seems to be the construction of a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) [spatial index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index#Spatial_index).

[image]

You can build it recursively starting from the top and building lower levels until your criteria (number of features per cell) is met.